# How to convert selection in JavaFX ComboBox to String

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, combobox, tostring

I have a form which is to be submitted to a mySQL database, where one of the inputs is a ComboBox (JavaFX).

When submitting the input from the ComboBox, the value added to the database is

```
"ComboBox[id=rolePicker, styleClass=combo-box-base combo-box]"
```

not a `String` value.

How can I solve this issue, so that the data submitted to the database is a `String` of the value selected?

(Partial) JAVA Controller Code:

```
public class NewUserController implements Initializable, ControlledScreen {

    @FXML
    TextField nameField;
    @FXML
    TextField usernameField;
    @FXML
    TextField emailField;
    @FXML
    ComboBox rolePicker;

    @FXML
    public void submitUser(ActionEvent event) {
        String dbUsername = "root";
        String dbPassword = "secret";
        String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/uia";

        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUsername, dbPassword);
            Statement statement = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
            statement.execute("INSERT INTO user (name, username, password, email, userrole) VALUES ('" + nameField.getText() + "', '" + usernameField.getText() + "', '" + usernameField.getText() + "', '" + emailField.getText() + "', '" + rolePicker + "');");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

(Partial) FXML Code:

```
<ComboBox id="rolePicker" fx:id="rolePicker" editable="true" maxHeight="25.0" maxWidth="225.0" minHeight="25.0" minWidth="225.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="225.0" promptText="Role.." visibleRowCount="4">
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="TEACHER" />
            <String fx:value="STUDENT" />
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the following line you use `rolePicker` in a string expression, therefore the compiler will call the `toString()` method on this object to get the string representation of the object, that causes the mentioned output:

```
statement.execute("INSERT INTO user (name, username, password, email, userrole) VALUES ('" + 
nameField.getText() + "', '" + usernameField.getText() + "', '" + usernameField.getText() + "', '" + emailField.getText() + 
"', '" + rolePicker + "');");
```

You should get the selected value of the `ComboBox` with [`getValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#getValue--) method:

```
rolePicker.getValue();
```

and you can use the returned value in the expression.

**Note:** `getValue` will return the type which type the `ComboBox` has as generic parameter (the type of the items stored in the `ComboBox`): `public final T getValue()`. In your current situation you have a `ComboBox` that stores `String` values (`ComboBox<String>`), therefore the returned value can be used directly.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm.